# Unclear CodenameOne error log

Tags: java, codenameone

When I try to build for windows phone, I get an error log of about 47MB and it's not really clear here the issue is at all. Is it normal that the error log is so large?

Anyway, the file is here: http://it-ca.net/Dylan/documents/error.txt (takes some time to load due to filesize)

Could you give me any insight in what the cause might be? Or how to interpret these error files?

thanks!

The thing is, from the first few lines, I'd gather it's an error in "impl.implementationFactory", but that doesn't help me :s

Executing:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar win_xmlvm.jar --in=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build5510534969425459840xxx\classes --resource=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build5510534969425459840xxx\MyApplication\MyApplication\res/ --out=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build5510534969425459840xxx\MyApplication\MyApplication\src --target=csharp --app-name=MyApplication 
[05/20/14 16:36:19.341]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory
[05/20/14 16:36:19.341]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory
NoSuchFieldError
UnsupportedOperationException
ReadWriteFloatArrayBuffer
XPathFactoryConfigurationException
SAXParser
XMLVMArray
IdFunction
AbstractStringBuilder
Collections_2SingletonMap_21_21
SupplRangeSet
LangFunction
NumberConverter
SAXParser
DeviceRunner
JavascriptContext
Deflate
ResourceBundle_2Control
ReadWriteCharArrayBuffer
HTMLForm_2NamedCommand
AbstractCharClass_2LazyJavaUnicodeIdentifierPart_21
ImageMapData
AccessController
Inflater
ArrayStoreException
AbstractCharClass_2LazyJavaLetter
XmlParser_2EntityInfo
CIDecomposedCharSet
DomHTMLHeadingElement
ProxySelector
Table_2Listener
Collections_2CheckedSortedSet
CloudStorage_21
FileChannel_2MapMode
CloudStorage_22
VirtualKeyboard_2InputField
EmailShare_21
Transition
EncodedImage
DomHTMLEmbedElement
DeflaterOutputStream
Matcher
AbstractCharClass_2LazyPrint
EmptyStackException
TimeZone
DomHTMLMenuElement
CPStringBuilder
DomXPathNSResolver
TreeMap_2BoundedEntryIterator
CompositeRangeSet
AbstractMap_21_21
HangulDecomposedCharSet
BigInteger
SerializablePermission
DomHTMLScriptElement
AdsService
DomHTMLParamElement
Process
SMSShare_21_22_22
IdentityHashMap_2IdentityHashMapIterator
NativeLookup
SMSShare_21_22_21
AtomicJointSet
CodenameOneImplementation_22_22
DomNamedNodeMap
HTMLParser
HTMLEventsListener_21
DateTimeRenderer
HTMLEventsListener_22
FBObject
LinkedHashMap_22
LinkedHashMap_21
DefaultDocumentRequestHandler
CodenameOneImplementation_22_21
FileNotFoundException
BufferedOutputStream
Calendar
SecurityManager
RedTypeMarker
StringBuilder
MultiComboBox
HexStringParser
IdentityHashMap_22_21
Collections_2SingletonSet_21
DomDoctype
DomHTMLAppletElement
Tabs_2TabFocusListener
DomHTMLTableRowElement
DataOutputStream
Collections_2SingletonSet
Preferences
Collections_2CheckedMap
DomHTMLLabelElement
PossessiveAltQuantifierSet
Message
OutOfMemoryError
HashSet
NullPointerException
BigDecimal
Contact
MappedByteBuffer
EmulatedFieldsForDumping
FilterProxyListModel_22
AbstractCharClass_2LazyJavaDigit_21
FilterProxyListModel_21
TextField
EmulatedFields
ValidationConsumer_2ChildrenRecognizer
Array
LSException
DomHTMLLinkElement
AbstractCharClass_2LazyDigit
GenericSignatureFormatError
AbstractCharClass_2LazyAlpha
LowHighSurrogateRangeSet
HashMap_2AbstractMapIterator
Object
DomHTMLUListElement
SMSShare
PropertyPermissionCollection
EmailShare_21_22_22
EmailShare_21_22_21
ContentHandler
TreeMap_2AscendingSubMapIterator
MathUtil
DomHTMLDocument
DomHTMLHeadElement
TreeMap_2UnboundedValueIterator
MultiButton
SideMenuBar_28_21_22
DomHTMLBRElement
InvalidObjectException
SideMenuBar_28_21_21
ReadWriteLongArrayBuffer
VirtualKeyboard_23
XPathParser_2YyTableClass
VirtualKeyboard_22
LinkedHashMap_2EntryIterator
VirtualKeyboard_21
GlassTutorial
String
FacebookShare_22_21
CoderMalfunctionError
FacebookShare_22_22
NumberFunction
CoderResult
DomHTMLMetaElement
AbstractCharClass_2LazyJavaTitleCase_21
AbstractCharClass_2LazyXDigit
PropertyResourceBundle
ThreadGroup
CSSBgPainter
DTDAttributeTypeInfo
Long
UnknownServiceException
MultiLineEOLSet
SequenceSet_2IntHash
PrivilegedActionException
DomConsumer
AbstractList_2SubAbstractList_2SubAbstractListIterator
UnicodeReader
Timer
CRLFReader
TranslateFunction
ConnectionRequest
HTMLComponent_2HTMLComboBox
HighSurrogateCharSet
Logical
InfBlocks
AndExpr
TreeMap_2Node
Error
TreeMap_2UnboundedEntryIterator
VirtualKeyboard
GridBagLayout_21
VariableReference
ObjectInputStream_21
ObjectInputStream_22
Dialog
GroupLayout_2SpringDelta
Container
List_2Listeners
Collections_2SynchronizedSortedMap
WeakHashMap_2HashIterator
XMLParser_2Attribute
CloudListModel_21
Element
CloudListModel_22
ValidationConsumer
LinkedHashMap_2ValueIterator
FileChannelFactory
FloatArrayBuffer
XMLParser_2ContentParticle
HTMLInputFormat_2FormatConstraint
CacheMap
GroupLayout_21
Capture_2CallBack
Hashtable_24_21
FloatToByteBufferAdapter
Proxy
DomNSResolverContext
JSONParser_2KeyStack
XmlReader
XPathConstants
IntToByteBufferAdapter
DomHTMLSelectElement
AbstractCharClass
DateSpinner_21
BackReferencedSingleSet
XMLParser_2Input
InfCodes
LinkedList_2Link
XPathParser_2YySindexClass
ResourceBundle_2NoFallbackControl
InetAddress
BufferFactory
ObjectStreamField_21
Collections_2UnmodifiableCollection_21
ActionEvent
DefaultHTMLCallback
ResultTokenizer
```

Comment: can you please quote like first ~50 lines of an error? In many cases first lines are the key to mystery. File size suggests that something is being thrown over and over again.

Comment: Sure no problem, I have added them :)

Comment: That seems to be a failure in the native build but I'm not sure I understand why. It seems to be related to an invalid space character somewhere maybe in the name of something?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog could be like looking for a needle in a haystack. The simulator runs the application as it should be, without any errors. I'll try and hunt the character down :/

Comment: Could it have something to do with the trailing forward slash in `--resource=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build5510534969425459840xxx\MyApplication\MyApplication\res/`? All other paths consistently use backward slahes.